# Workflow automation: Makefile vs. Ant

Tags: ant, automation, makefile

Whenever I notice that something in my workflow is a **repeating task**, I try to automate it.

For example the steps necessary to deploy something on a server. It's often a build, followed by a **scp** and finally some remote setup scripts:

1. mvn package
2. scp target/foobar.jar  server:
3. ssh server install-foobar
4. ssh server './bin/foobar restart'

I tend to write a small Makefile in such cases, which could look like

```
  deploy:
      mvn package
      scp target/foobar.jar server:
      ssh server install-foobar
      ssh server './bin/foobar restart'
```

How do *you* automate your workflows?
Is Ant the tool of choice? What are the Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 2):

For Java development, I'd say Ant is the default choice.

**Pro:**

- good documentation,

  good IDE integration

  Lots of third-party extensions and tools

**Con:**

- Somewhat verbose (well, it's yet anothr XML format)

  Some things that should be simple aren't (e.g. any kind of looping)

I don't really have any experience using makefiles, so I can't say how they compare. Maybe you should simply use what your developers are more experienced with.

Comment: ant-contrib can be used to easily add loops to ant scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[SCons](http://www.scons.org/) is another good one.  And [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) seems to be well regarded although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I use shell and perl scripts

Answer (score 1):

consider GAnt (http://gant.codehaus.org/). using Groovy's builder, it is much less verbose than an Ant build script

Comment: Ey, this look fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

For python I tend to use [fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/)  for the deployment steps and [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) for any building that is needed (not that usual for me :-)

Fabric understands how to copy files to servers, runing commands on the remote server (both as the standard user and as root).

Answer (score 1):

one of the reasons most build systems are so complex is that folks try and do to much in them. sometimes complementing a build system with a driver-script that takes care of non compilation/linking tasks is a good way to go. There is no single way. Its hard to answer the question without see the project source code structure and all the tasks that need to be done. But you might want to take a look at Rake as it would complement Make, Ant, and Maven

Answer (score 0):

Rake is my choice.

Answer (score 0):

I find Ant and its XML configuration syntax a bit unwieldy and there are some things that should be trivial but are very hard to get in Ant. I prefer for that kind of automation [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

There is another tool precisely made to deploy stuff that I used for a bit and was pretty cool, but I forgot its name, maybe somebody else remembers it :).

Answer (score 0):

I use scripts (shell, perl, python) or makefiles. I do not like Ant and SCons